# How to deal with common checks in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Let's say, I have an ASP.NET MVC controller with the usual add, update, delete, and details actions.

In each action I have to check if the passed in ID matches with an existing database object and if it doesn't return a 404.

Sometimes I also have to check if the current user is authorized for this particular object or some other test.

I often end up writing a lot of duplicate code, like this, in a couple of controller actions:

```
Foo foo = DataContext.Foos.Find(id);

if(foo == null)
    return HttpNotFound("The requested foo does not exist");

if(!foo.Users.Any(x => x.Username == User.Identity.Name))
    throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized access");
```

Is there a better way to 'automatically' perform/include/inject such tests for certain actions?

Comment: Custom attribute? Shared function? Lots of ways!

Comment: Action Filters? - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called [Apecct Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). The article has a list of frameworks for this in .NET.